# Phonegap - Android Back button - how to catch press hold event

Tags: android, cordova

Is it possible to capture a press and hold event of an Android Devices back button to close the app?

Cheers
Paul

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yes, see the PhoneGap API:
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_events_events.md.html

```
// Call onDeviceReady when PhoneGap is loaded.
//
// At this point, the document has loaded but phonegap.js has not.
// When PhoneGap is loaded and talking with the native device,
// it will call the event `deviceready`.
// 
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// PhoneGap is loaded and it is now safe to make calls PhoneGap methods
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    // Register the event listener
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
}

// Handle the back button
//
function onBackKeyDown() {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No there isn't a listener only for that but I think you can make your own long back key listener by using `onKeyDown()` listener or even better, you could give a try with `onLongKeyDown()` listener...

Good luck!